# Shutdown a subdomain can affect another subdomain

Tags: seo, google, subdomain, googlebot, multiple-domains

I have two subdomains and I decided to shutdown the br and focus only in pt project.

```
https://pt.example.com
https://br.example.com
```

My question is that I have some old posts (archived and not available to edit) in forums that have the link `https://br.example.com`

So, it is a broken link now. My question is if that can have some negative impact in pt subdomain? Or can just ignore these old posts?

Comment: Is the content the same between the two subdomains?   `pt.` and `br.` are often two Portuguese subdomains with the same content but targeted at users in Portugal and Brazil respectively.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, the content is different, and targeting different countries. Each domain is completely isolated.

Comment: Isolated is better for this purpose. Do the inter link at all?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, they are absolutely unlinked. Only the flag icon has a href that make some some connection between sites.

Comment: Is that flag icon only on the home page or on every page?    If it is on every page, then your subdomains are very tightly linked.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, only in landing page.

Comment: It's going to be hard to give you a definitive answer to this question.  For SEO it is generally better to leave old content up.   You generally would only want to take content down if it is a lot of work to keep it up to date and having stale content makes your whole site look bad.   It is certainly possible that taking down a subdomain could hurt the rankings of the other.   The fact that they are not closely linked makes that less likely though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now a days major search engines like google considers Subdomain as independent site so deleting a it doesn't make any problem for SEO even you have submitted the sitemap for it and pages had indexed. It won't affect your other subdomain or domain.